# JavaFX Platform.runLater() after site reload

Tags: java, swing, applet, javafx

I am writing an Java Applet using JavaFX embedded in Swing. Users are able to start a Swing-GUI with JavaFX components using JFXPanel with the following code:

```
group = AccessController.doPrivileged(new ProxyNewGroup());
fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /* Create some objects and add them to group */
        ...
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }
};
jFrame.add(fxPanel);
```

When the Applet starts first the user can create the GUI element and close it. Later he can recreate. To do so I need to hold an invisible JFrame containig a JFXPanel the whole runtime in memory, that I never use, because I read somewhere that otherwise the JavaFX-Application-Thread is stopped. The problem now is that when the user reloads the page the run-method won't get executed and I don't get any error message or exception.

I wrote an own class implementing runnable with a custom constructor. The constructor is called and runs till the end but the run-Method wont get started. I also tried do all work within the AccessController, but this also didn't work.

I really don't no how to solve this problem and appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I tried some more things:

1. I examinated the running threads. When I start the Applet-GUI there is a JavaFX Application Thread and a QuantumRenderer thread. When I reload the webpage, the threads won't show up again. Whenn reloading the Webpage befor I opened the GUI (and create the threads) everything works fine, but afert a second reload it fails.
2. I tried using *Platform.setImplicitExit(false)*. With this option I don't need my background-object any more. When reloading the webpage I get a *QuantumRenderer-0 uncaught: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException* and the Java Console closes. When starting the Applet everything works fine on my computer, but I don't want to crash Java and this approach didn't work on a different pc with same Java-version (8).

Maybe this informations are helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved this, but maybe this http://news.kynosarges.org/2014/05/01/simulating-platform-runandwait/ can help you

> runLater swallows any exceptions that the executed action might throw,
>   as it’s not designed to communicate anything back to the caller. If
>   you want error handling you need to specialize runAndWait for a
>   Runnable subclass that provides such communication